# Get class and activity name from apk to execute

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, apk

I want to execute Amazone2.2.apk from my script in emulator or device. For it i need class name and home activity package name.

Any one help me how i can get the class and activity name from apk?

I ahve tried and got com.amazon.mShop.android and com.amazon.mShop.home.HomeActivity but my script told ClassNotFoundException on com.amazon.mShop.home.HomeActivity

Thanks,

Comment: How it is not a programming question and about android usage??? could u plz explain??

Answer (score 0):

`aapt dump badging Your.apk`

and get the activity name.